# Adding amount to cart when input field is filled

Tags: custom-field, input

I am trying to add a custom input field to a single product template in WooCommerce, which would add a fee of $20 to the cart total if the customer inputs data in the field. I have added a custom input field above Add to Cart with this hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'inscription_text', 9 );

function inscription_text() {
    $value = isset( $_POST['custom_text_add_on'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_text_add_on'] ) : '';
    echo '<div style="width:100%"><label>Add inscription (+$20):</label><p><input placeholder="Your inscription" style="box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px solid;" maxlength="40" name="custom_text_add_on" value="' . $value . '"></p></div>';
}
```

The input field is displayed and works fine. I then want to add $20 to the cart total if and only if an inscription is entered in the input field. So far no success. This is what I have tried but it does not work:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','add_inscription_fee' );

function add_inscription_fee() {
    if( isset( $_POST['custom_text_add_on'] ) ) {
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Inscription', 20 );
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I can guess that the condition is not evaluated because I need to pass a variable to the function, but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!